# Tampermonkey Userscript doesn't work on file://

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am running very simple script to change the background color of few matching text.

Filename: `summary.log`

file location: `file://172.199.13.11/Logs/Summary.log`

Structure

```
<html>
<head>
<body><pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
</head>
</html>
```

When I load this file I want to highlight few text

```
Var myArray= ("ERROR","FAILURE","WARNING","DEBUG")
```

Can you please help me to provide a script by which I can change the background color to red when I load a log file from server.

Answer (score 1):

remove the 172.199.13.11/ if it is a "local file" ... its should be a full path .... unless in fact "172.199.13.11" is a directory you have inside your root directory